# installed ubuntu 12.04 on a hp 14 chromebook.. there is no ubuntu software center, or browser

Tags: installation, unity, software-center, chromebook

it wcs a successful installation, with a quick switch option  between ubuntu and chromeOS without rebooting. However it installed without the ubuntu software center. I am a noobie, and i cannot install any software....Ive tried "sudo apt-get software-center", "sudo apt-get software"  i get "invalid operation"    Help!

Comment: to install packages, simply: `sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME`. I would install ubuntu-desktop (since it didn't work fully). and do system updates.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

you forgot the "install" in your command

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+alt+t , it will open your terminal , then write sudo apt-get install software-centre , it will install your ubuntu software centre then use it to install further packages .